# When using CGContextDrawPath, how do you avoid drawing the lines between shapes?

Tags: xcode, swift, core-graphics

I'm trying to draw a series of small circles but when I use CGContextDrawPath it fills in the line in between the circles that I have added to the path. Here is the code:

```
  var radius: CGFloat = 3
  var bulletSpacing: CGFloat = 10
  var numberOfBullets = 5

  override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    for i in 1...numberOfBullets{
      CGContextAddArc(ctx, CGFloat(Float(i) * Float(bulletSpacing)), self.frame.size.height/2, radius, 0, CGFloat(2 * M_PI), 0)
    }

    CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapButt)
    CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathStroke)
```

Is there a way to avoid drawing the path in between the circles? This is what it ends up looking like: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for `CGContextAddArc()` (emphasis added):

> Adds an arc of a circle to the current path, **possibly preceded by a straight line segment** … If the current path already contains a subpath, Quartz **adds a line connecting the current point to the starting point of the arc**. … The ending point of the arc becomes the new current point of the path.

So, after an arc, the ending point of the arc becomes the current point of the path. Then, when the next arc is added, a line from the previous arc's ending point to the new arc's starting point is added.

One solution is to move the current point to the new arc's starting point immediately before adding it. You can use:

```
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, CGFloat(Float(i) * Float(bulletSpacing)) + radius, self.frame.size.height/2)
```

Another solution is to draw and clear the path after adding each arc. Move your call to `CGContextSetLineCap()` to before the loop and your call to `CGContextDrawPath()` into the loop.